# MSSQL COALESCE function with multiple non null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce, ignition

I am trying to get data (T_Stamp, Destination, Weight, Line) from two tables using variable time intervals and a destination selection. This is going into an Ignition SCADA. My SQL code below works for most cases except when there are entries into both tables with the same timestamp. In those cases it shows only the data from table A. This is giving me results with the incorrect destination. I understand that the COALESCE function is returning the first Non-null value, but I don't know how else to write this logic.

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.t_stamp, b.t_Stamp) T_Stamp, COALESCE(a.Destination, b.Destination) Destination, COALESCE(a.A_Weight, b.B_Weight) Weight, CASE WHEN a.Ham_Line_A_Counts_ndx > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS Line
FROM Ham_Line_A_Counts as a FULL OUTER JOIN 
     b_Counts AS b
      ON a.t_Stamp=b.t_Stamp
WHERE (a.t_Stamp Between '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}' AND '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}' AND a.Destination = {Root Container.Dropdown 1.selectedValue}) OR (b.t_Stamp Between '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}' AND '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}' AND b.Destination = {Root Container.Dropdown 1.selectedValue})
ORDER BY T_Stamp DESC
```

Expected results:

| t_stamp | Destination | Weight | Line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:05:01 | 1 | 30.01 | A |
| 10:05:05 | 1 | 25.11 | B |
| 10:05:07 | 1 | 26.32 | B |

Actual Results:

| t_stamp | Destination | Weight | Line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:05:01 | 1 | 30.01 | A |
| 10:05:05 | 1 | 25.11 | B |
| 10:05:07 | 2 | 25.46 | A |

Sample Data
Table A:
| t_stamp  | Destination | A_Weight |
| -------- | ----------- | -------- |
| 10:05:01 |      1      |   30.01  |
| 10:05:07 |      2      |   32.32  |

Table B:
| t_stamp  | Destination | B_Weight |
| -------- | ----------- | -------- |
| 10:05:03 |      1      |   24.01  |
| 10:05:07 |      1      |   26.46  |

Comment: Using `where` with `full join` is really tricky.  Are you sure you need `full join`?  Sample data and a clear description of the logic would help.

Comment: Thank you for your response @GordonLinoff
I currently have two tables. Table A has Columns: t_stamp, Destination, and A_Weight ;Table B has Columns: t_stamp, Destination, and B_Weight
I'm trying to get one table with columns: t_stamp, Destination, and Weight using a 'Where' statement for the t_stamp and Destination columns. On some occasions I get entries into both tables with the same t_stamp value which causes my 'Coalesce' statement to just choose the value from column A regardless if it is has the correct destination value. Is there a different type of Join I should be using?

Comment: If you want the data `b` first, instead of `a`, why not just reverse the parameters in `COALESCE`?

Comment: you need to provide sample data

Comment: All the details that directly related to the question can be added via *edit* link below the question. It will be more useful to get all the input directly from question, not from reading all the comments.

Comment: What should happen if there is a record with the same timestamp in both tables? If you want B instead of A, you can reverse the order of the `COALESCE` (as mentioned in a previous comment). If you want both rows, then this should probably be a `UNION` of some sort instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: What is the "correct" destination value? That seems to be the heart of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you want is something like the following, which uses a `UNION` instead of a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.t_stamp T_Stamp, a.Destination Destination, a.A_Weight Weight, 'A' Line
FROM Ham_Line_A_Counts a
WHERE a.t_Stamp Between '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}' AND '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}' AND a.Destination = {Root Container.Dropdown 1.selectedValue}
UNION ALL
SELECT b.t_stamp T_Stamp, b.Destination Destination, b.B_Weight Weight, 'B' Line
FROM b_Counts b
WHERE b.t_Stamp Between '{Root Container.Popup Calendar.date}' AND '{Root Container.Popup Calendar 1.date}' AND b.Destination = {Root Container.Dropdown 1.selectedValue})
ORDER BY T_Stamp DESC
```

This gets the results from `a` with the correct destination and timestamps, gets the results from `b` with the correct destination and timestamps, then sorts them all together by timestamp. So if a timestamp is in `a` and `b`, both rows are returned one after the other. I used `UNION ALL` rather than just `UNION` since the hardcoded 'A'/'B' in the `Line` column means there won't be duplicates and the `UNION ALL` could be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I tried UNION ALL earlier and didn't return any results. Now I see that I was using it incorrectly. 

I seldom use SQL as a controls engineer and am still learning. I appreciate everyone's help.